# How to find the constant c in big-Omega notation

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

According to my information, we say that f(n) is Ω(g(n)), if g(n) is O(f(n)), that is, there is a real constant c > 0 and an integer constant n_0 >= 1 such that

```
f(n) >= cg(n),   for n >= n_0
```

for example,

```
3nlogn + 4n + 5logn is Ω(nlogn)
```

Then according to definition, `f(n) = 3nlogn + 4n + 5logn` and `g(n) = nlogn`,  the value of c must be 1, right? But then every question we solve will have c = 1.  on the other hand if we put c = 3 (coefficient of g(n)), does it give the correct answer? How to find correct value of c?